# Angular - Set initial value for JSON select-option

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to set initial value in select-option. Here is my code :

```
<select ng-init="blah" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in cities "ng-model="selectedCity" ng-click="setCity()" class="form-control"></select>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `selectedCity = 'someValue'`

Comment: `ng-init="selectedCity=initialVal.cities"` //initialVal is the value you want to select.

Comment: @Satpal <select ng-init="selectedCity = 'someValue'" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in cities "ng-model="selectedCity" ng-click="setCity()" class="form-control"></select> it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting it within the markup (which is **not** recommended ) use

```
<select ng-init="selectedCity='firstCity'" 
    ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in cities"
    ng-model="selectedCity">
</select>
```

`firstCity` is the key you want to be selected by default.

Lets say this is your object

```
$scope.cities = {
    firstCity: "NY",
    secondCity: "LA",
    thirdCity: "OT"
  };
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/2uLq8gee/)**

For initializing in controller use

```
$scope.selectedCity='firstCity';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will work, but I really think `ng-init` should be avoided (and the Angular docs [recommend initializing values in your controller rather than using it for that purpose too](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)). Putting logic in your views makes your code a lot harder to follow. Obviously this sort of thing is a matter of taste, though!

Comment: Yes @JoeClay . But the post author reads as **I want to set initial value in select-option** thats why I posted this. Thanks BTW. I've edited my post too

Comment: Yeah, your post definitely answers the question, so I didn't vote it down - even if your answer isn't how I'd personally do it, it's good to let the post author know of all of the available options :)

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat if I have three key-value pair and I want to set  first value as default value , How I initialize initialVal?

Comment: @afn Please check the edited answer and the working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you just need to initialilize `selectedCity` to the value you want it defaulted to.

Comment: I initialize selectedCity  in my controller but still it doesn't work :
Controller : 
$scope.selectedCity = 'NY';

HTML : 
<select ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in cities "ng-model="selectedCity" ng-click="setCity()" class="form-control"></select>

Answer (score 0):

In your controller declare :

```
 $scope.selectedCity = 'cityName'; // any name you want to initialize with
```

Comment: `$scope.cities` is not an array.